# Windows: wait for process to finish

Tags: windows, shell, directx

I have to make a short Windows shell script. Please don't run away. It couldn't be simpler, but I just can't find the way to make this frankly primitive command-line to work with me.

I simply want to run `dxdiag`, and do something with the gathered data.

Thing is, I can't get the script to **wait** for `dxdiag` to finish, since it spawns the process and keeps on going. I need the file to exist and have the information before moving on to the next line.

Using `start /wait` has no effect, I'm guessing because there's no GUI involved.

I'm starting to think this isn't possible. Please help!

Comment: It would help if you specified windows version...

Comment: I'm struggling in Windows 7, but this should work for XP+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried something like this

```
start /wait dxdiag /x:SomeXmlFile
```

And it is working for me in Windows Vista.

Comment: Hmmm not working in Windows 7 for me. I think I'll just loop until the file exists.

Comment: @Santiago Use caution if looping until file exists, since you could try to access the file before the dxdiag has finished creating it (really depends on how dxdiag works with files). If

Comment: I'm waiting a couple of seconds between loop passes. The chance that I catch the file in mid-writing are slim, and honestly, I'm content with that haha. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Do something similar to THIS code:

```
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq dxdiag.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "dxdiag.exe">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" goto next_area_here
```

- if errorlevel is returned as 0, dxdiag in this case is CLOSED
- if errorlevel returned as 1, dxdiag in this case is OPEN